# Log errors on SQLException to table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have stored procedures that are likes this overall:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS; # this shows a result set with the errors that occured
        ROLLBACK; # this rollbacks all the magic i tried to to, making this whole stuff atomic, YAY! 
    insert into LogTest select 1,2; # this is just a test to make sure it would work
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    # do some magic
    COMMIT
END
```

Now, what i need to do is change the Handler to something like this, obviously ***semi-pseudocode***:

```
DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK; # this rollbacks all the magic i tried to to, making this whole stuff atomic, YAY! 
    insert into LogTest # and this tells me what timey whimey hit the maelstorm
    select now(),*,'some id', ... <some more stuff maybe?>
      from (Show errors) as Errors
END;
```

Any one any experience/idea/knowledge?